# Can "wildlife" be a collective noun?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

All dictionaries I have checked list the term *wildlife* as an uncountable noun. But there are plenty of examples that treat *wildlife* as a plural. Indeed, Google returns around one million search results for the phrase "wildlife that is," much fewer than the over 2.7 million for "wildlife that are."

I've found it difficult to wrap my head around this word: Is this an uncountable noun as the dictionaries say or can this be sometimes treated as a collective noun that can represent a plural?

Why do the mainstream dictionaries all proclaim *wildlife* as an uncountable noun while people frequently treat it as a plural?

Comment: It seems an obvious mistake to make: there is often confusion between whether to use singular or plural with collective nouns, and confusion over what nouns count as collective nouns (e.g. company is a collective noun, but what about firm or business? Organisation, club, society?). And different dialects have different rules about collective nouns (particularly US vs UK English). Since wildlife generally refers to multiple animals, it's natural to suspect it might take a plural. Follow what dictionaries say in formal writing, but be understanding of people's mistakes.

Comment: Why don't the dictionaries catch every single nuance of usage that English native speakers make? Because they only have a limited number of resources available, and they generally copy each other, so once one dictionary has made a mistake the others also make the same mistake. Ignore the dictionaries — there's nothing wrong with using a plural verb with *wildlife*.

Comment: This looks like it is a usage in flux. Some people will say that plural agreement is acceptable, while some will say that it is increasingly seen but still unacceptable. Be aware that both schools exist, and that there will be people trying to say that their school alone is correct. Make sure that you know your prof's / editor's attitude here. If you're writing for a general audience, be prepared for disapproval if you choose a less traditional usage. You can always reword.

Comment: Check your definition of *collective noun*.  “I do not think it means what you think it means.”

Comment: The question you're asking can be asked of any word. "Why do people say ungrammatical things?" There are many reasons, but there's nothing particular to wildlife. As another reference point, I've never heard anyone say *wildlife are*, so this looks like it varies by region.

Comment: You’ve asked about collective nouns and noncount nouns. *Wildlife* is noncount; there is no *wildlives*. In American English, you would be hard pressed to hear *wildlife* being used with plural agreement. **The wildlife are competing among themselves for resources.* (No.) Neither would we say: **The wildlife is competing among itself for resources.* (No.) We would find a plural noun: *The animals are competing among themselves for resources.* Or, if meaning suggests: *The wildlife is competing with humans for resources.*

Comment: I wonder why a substantially high proportion of people treat "wildlife" as a plural noun. Google gives back a much greater number of search results for the seemingly wrong "wildlife that are" than for the dictionary-complying "wildlife that is." It returns around 2.9 million results for the phrase "wildlife is," compared with a still-not-negligible 900k for "wildlife are."

Comment: I haven't heard wildlife being used as a plural noun. It think it can be used like 'committee, police' etc.

Comment: By "plural noun," I mean the treatment of "wildlife" as a plural, like the phrase "wildlife that are." The focus here is whether "wildlife" is an uncountable noun as all the major dictionaries calls for or a collective noun, the grouping that includes "committee" and "police."

Comment: "*People are strange*" "*The police were here last night*" Some plural nouns do not take the -s suffix. If the noun "wildlife" was countable, we would read and write about "wildlives" but in English it's always *wildlife*, and **how people interpret that word is flexible**. Do we consider it as an entirety, as if it were similar to a team or a family–a single unit–or do we think about  the variety of species, the fauna and also the flora that inhabits an area? Different people will use the term in different ways.

Comment: Check your search methods. From the corpus: _Both **public health and wildlife are** placed at risk..._ _**Turtles, birds, and other wildlife are** continually confused by the lights in cities..._ _**Many campaigns to help wildlife are** underway..._ Of course there would be no singular agreements here. But *wildlife* by itself takes a singular agreement in AmE.

Comment: The definition of 'collective noun' needs stipulating. 'Cattle' is a singular-form (not 'cattles') non-count (we can't say '5 cattle') though etically denumerable (there are 5 cows and a bull in that field) noun taking a plural verb form. I wouldn't call it a 'collective noun'.

Comment: My Ngram viewer does not support your Google search results.  It would appear that *Wildlife Is* is the more common form.    https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wildlife+is%2Cwildlife+are%2Cwildlife+that+is%2Cwildlife+that+are&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer from [another site](https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst8329_plural-and-singular-.aspx):

> Well, actually this is a little more complicated than it first seems, because "wildlife" is different from "life."
>
> "Wildlife" is what is known as a **collective noun**, meaning there is more than one member. "Family" is a similar, collective noun.
>
> **Most of the time, collective nouns are treated as singular:**
>
> "The family is eating dinner."
> Most of the time, a family is considered a unit, with much more in common than otherwise, and thus treated as a unitary noun.
>
> **Sometimes, collective nouns are treated as plurals:**
>
> "The family are fighting over Uncle John's will."
>
> In this case, the predominant consideration is for the members as individuals and what they are doing as individuals.
>
> "The crew is bringing the ship into port."
> "The crew are bringing the ship into port."
> This is a trickier case, and neither use (plural v. singular) is incorrect.
> If one is considering the crew as a team and the team actions to be coordinated, and if that is what one focuses on, then "is" would be correct.
>
> If, on the other hand, one focuses on the individual tasks of the crew members and consider that some are concerned with the ship itself, some with passengers and baggage, and conceivably some with freight, then "are" would be correct.
>
> **"Wildlife," itself, may be used either way:**
>
> Wildlife is in danger from climate change. (Thinking of the whole, experiencing the same threat.)
>
> The wildlife of the area are beautiful. (Thinking of each specie [sic] as its own object of beauty.)
>
> Or even:
>
> As the climate of the area changes, the wildlife are adjusting, and some species may go extinct, while others increase.

By [RuthP](https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/profile601850.aspx)

Comment: What's this about *specie* now? That's a money thing.

Comment: @tchrist Must be a typo.

Comment: What do you think about the fact that all the major dictionaries define "wildlife" as an uncountable noun, not a collective noun? In fact, if "wildlife" were defined as a collective noun, I would have no problem with comprehending this word in the first place.

Comment: I don't think "collective noun" is a label dictionaries use even for collective nouns. I would look at grammar books instead of dictionaries to see if a noun is a collective noun. "Wildlife" is peculiar in that it _is_ a mass noun consisting of individuals (i.e., animals), when prototypical collective nouns (e.g., family, crew, etc.) are all count nouns. But it's clear that it does denote collectivity: it's defined as "Wild animals collectively" at https://www.lexico.com/definition/wildlife

Comment: British English.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Good point.

Comment: ' "Wildlife" is what is known as a collective noun, meaning there is more than one member ' is so misleading that I feel it shouldn't be perpetuated.

Comment: The lack of parallel construction in your souce's last paragraph is grating enough that I have a hard time taking it seriously.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth eh? Misleading how? I might have said it differently, but what other criteria are there? What restrictions? MW uses the same definition - a noun that refers to a group of people or things.

Comment: Perhaps the most typical occurrences of collective nouns are in the 'a set/group of ...' phrases. 'A pride of lions.' 'A pack of cards.' 'Three families of badgers.' These are count usages. Yes, what are arguably collective noun usages without the of-phrase exist: 'My family have all had Covid.' 'The jury were arguing among themselves.' But note that these are again count usages: ''Those five families all live near the forest.'  'The three juries all failed to bring in guilty verdicts.' But  'We see a wildlife of animals'? 'Two wildlifes that coexist are ,,,'? No. 'Wildlife', like 'fauna', ...

Comment: is usually treated as a non-count noun. 'The wildlife in the region is very diverse' (not 'are'), just like 'the fauna shows great diversity'. **_If_** 'wildlife' has recently been countified, or may be treated as an invariant plural and used like 'cattle', which questions underpin OP's query, this must be endorsed by relevant authoritative references.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thankyou, I didn't realize non-count nouns weren't considered collective as well. I thought the idea included both count and non count. It gets kind of strange doing it this way when you consider words like *aggregate*, clearly a count noun, which is composed of sand and gravel.

Comment: 'Aggregate' has both count and non-count usages. Calling such nouns 'count nouns' is again very misleading: {[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aggregate) has: '**aggregate** noun [C or U]...' eg 'There are a lot of different aggregates available through the likes of ballast suppliers' [C] [[Springbridge](https://www.springbridge.co.uk/blog/the-different-types-of-aggregate-and-their-uses)] 'The typical concrete pavers (the ones where the aggregate is visible) seem to be using sand and aggregate..' [U] [[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/AngryWhiteMan)]

Answer (score 1):

> All dictionaries I have checked list the term wildlife as an uncountable noun. But there are plenty of examples that treat wildlife as a plural.
>
> I've found it difficult to wrap my head around this word: Is this an uncountable noun as the dictionaries say or can this be sometimes treated as a <s>collective</s> **mass** noun that can represent a plural?

Wildlife is a mass noun – broadly, it encompasses a group that shares the homogenous characteristics of moving and being alive and wild. As such, it is uncountable, i.e. it doesn’t have a plural form; it can’t be qualified by a number, and its quantifier is “much”, not “many.”

**Does it take a plural verb?**

Consider:
1 “The team **is** playing well.”

2 “The team **are** playing well.”

In **British English**, both are correct and have different nuances:

In 1, we have “The team, considered as a single unit, **is** playing well.” -> **It** is playing well.

In 2, we have “The team, considered as 11 individual players, **are** playing well”, i.e. the players of the team are playing well.” -> **They** are playing well.

Now:

3 “The wildlife in the area **is** suffering” -> this is the preferred version as "wildlife" (unlike "team") is uncountable.

4 “The wildlife in the area **are** suffering” -> this is often incorrectly used by speakers of British English based upon the "team" example above. However, it does not sound "awful" and would normally be overlooked.

In 3, “The wildlife” is considered as a single whole unit, and **is** suffering” -> **It** is suffering

In 4, “The wildlife” is considered as individual animals/birds/insects, etc. -> **They** are suffering.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not countable but here are some examples about your argument. You said "wildlife that are": [Examples of "wildlife that are"](https://lengusa.com/sentence-examples/wildlife%20that%20are).

Even if this returns something, they are mostly grouped with something else, so ***wildlife*** itself still is not plural.

Comparison if it helps: [Comparison between "wildlife that is" and "wildlife that are"](https://lengusa.com/sentence-examples/wildlife%20that%20are%20VS%20wildlife%20that%20is).

Comment: There are some lousy examples here given in trying to prove “wildlife” to not be a collective noun. The evidence in https://lengusa.com/sentence-examples/wildlife%20that%20are%20VS%20wildlife%20that%20is is all wrong, since the subject of the sentence in every case isn’t even the word “wildlife!” For instance, in the sentence "Our results represent the first evidence that numerous species of wildlife are now abundant . . .” the words “are now abundant” are referring to “species,” NOT “wildlife!” That “lengusa” is misrepresenting their examples. And in doing so, they fail to prove their point.